# when I give the command code. in gitbash it gives command not found and I have also installed vs code.any solution to this problem?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, git-bash

when I give the command `code.` in git bash, it gives me a command not found error. I have Visual Studio Code installed. Is there any solution to this problem?

Comment: Does `ls /usr/local/bin/code` show anything?

Comment: I am actually new to git have seen this  by some YouTubers , so I tried it but not able to get it .

Comment: `code` command is usually installed automatically when VS Code is. Please run the command I suggested to see if `code` even exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think You have omitted space after "code" word.

Type "code" one space and then "." (dot)

So not `code.` , you want `code .`

Comment: If this is the issue, then please may you flag the question as a typo?